# Query working in development but not in production Django

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I have a query which is something like that:

```
log_entry = LogEntry.objects.filter(Q(date__range=[start_date, end_date]) & Q(
    student_id__id__icontains=student) & Q(instructor_id__id__icontains=instructor) & Q(aircraft_id__id__icontains=aircraft))
log_entry_dual = LogEntry.objects.filter(Q(date__range=[start_date, end_date]) & Q(
    student_id__id__icontains=student) & Q(instructor_id__id__icontains=instructor) & Q(aircraft_id__id__icontains=aircraft) & Q(solo_flight=False))
```

and the view part which is:

```
start_date = request.GET.get('start_date')
if not start_date:
    start_date = dt.now().date()
end_date = request.GET.get('end_date')
if not end_date:
    end_date = dt.now().date()
student = request.GET.get('student')
if not student:
    student = ''
instructor = request.GET.get('instructor')
if not instructor:
    instructor = ''
aircraft = request.GET.get('aircraft')
if not aircraft:
    aircraft = ''
```

Now, the weird part is that this query and view works perfectly in development environment (it filters the results based on my input, so an empty field shows all the data based on the other filters) but in production (I am on heroku) doesn't work. I mean, it works ONLY if I choose ALL the fields of the query and I don't leave any blank input.
I have postgresql in both development and production.
Any clue about what I am doing wrong?

Comment: dt.now().date(), is your date create problem in local it takes your system time but in production it will take UTC

Comment: What is `__id__icontains=...` supposed to do? It is weird to perform a `icontains` on an `IntegerField`.